# Oracle 10g: ORA-12154 when connect to database with newly created user

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

This is the continue topic with this topic:

[Oracle 10g: Error when creating database manually by scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758534/oracle-10g-error-when-creating-database-manually-by-scripts)

Basically, I had created an Oracle database named "testdb" using only batch scripts and SQL scripts.

After successfully creating a database using script, I create a script to create user for client connect to the database.

**CreateUser.bat**

```
sqlplus sys/test as sysdba @D:\Script\CreateUser.sql
```

**CreateUser.sql**

```
shutdown immediate;
startup;
CREATE USER usr1 IDENTIFIED BY usr1
    DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
    QUOTA UNLIMITED ON users;
GRANT CREATE SESSION, GRANT ANY privilege TO usr1;
exit;
```

Everything run ok, with no error.

Then I try to test by connecting to SQLPlus on cmd:

```
sqlplus usr1/usr1@testdb
```

This retrun the error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I wonder what I did wrong.

The same happen for the database I created via DBCA.

Comment: Is `testdb` an alias in your `tnsnames.ora`? The error suggests it is not. You can put it there manually or use the net manager tool. But if the database is local, and you have `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID` set properly already, why aren't you just connecting locally now? Why go through TNS at all? It isn't anything to do with the user, anyway, the error is complaining about the connect identifier, which is the `testdb` part.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about :D. I am really unfamiliar with Oracle, so I am not sure about TNS, but during my database creating, I did not come across any of it setting. You can check my link at the top to see the script I used to create database [testdb]

Comment: Very, very short version: try `sqlplus usr1/usr1`. The `@testdb` attempts to use an alias defined in `tnsnames.ora` to access the database over SQl*Net. You don't need to do that if you're connecting from the same machine the database is on.

Comment: Thanks. I had done it before, and I know that it works. However, the problem is that I feel really uncomfortable with that kind of connection. Let say I have another database name [testdb_2] that has same structure as the [testdb] but with different set of data. When I connect with "sqlplus usr1/usr1", and type INSERT [something]. How can I know which database the script will run on.

Comment: It depends on your `ORACLE_SID` setting. There are ways to change your SQL*Plus prompt to show you the database name which can be a useful visual clue. But back to your question... you should [read up on naming methods](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm). With 'easy connect' you can do `sqlplus usr1/usr1@//hostname:port/testdb1`, where `hostname` either `localhost` or the servers real name depending on how things are configured, 1521 is the default listener port, and `testdb1` is the service name. Do `lsnrctl status` to verify what those should be.

Comment: But this is too broad an area to explain all the options and nuances; certainly in comments...

Comment: Thanks Alex, "sqlplus usr1/usr1@//localhost/testdb" works fine, and it is enough for my task. Now, how can I set this question as "answered" and close the topic?

Comment: I've summarised the comments into an answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you don't seem to have an entry for `testdb` in your `tnsnames.ora` file. You could add one, manually or with the configuration tools `netca` etc); or you could bypass that with the 'easy connect' syntax:

```
 sqlplus username/password@//hostname:port/service_name
```

If this is on your local machine, the default port and the service name matches the SID, that could be simolified a bit to:

```
sqlplus usr1/usr1@//localhost/testdb
```

You can verify the service name in `v$parameters`, or with `lsnrctl services`.

You can [read more about connections and naming methods](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm).

If your are connecting to a database on the same machine as the client, and you are using the same `ORACLE_HOME`, you don't need to use TNS/SQL*Net at all. With `ORACLE_SID` set to the right value, just doing this will connect locally:

```
sqlplus usr1/usr1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sqlplus usr1/usr1@testdb when you create connect string. It means that you need to entry in tnsnames.ora file